# disable all dbt models in a folder

Tags: dbt

I have a dbt project with the following directory structure:

```
├── models
│   ├── experiments
│   │   ├── experiment_1
│   │   ├── experiment_2
│   │   ├── experiment_3
│   │   ├── experiment_4
│   │   ├── experiment_5
│   │   └── experiment_6
```

with each `experiment_*` directory containing a number of models.

Is there a way to blanket disable, say, all models belonging to `experiment_4`?

I know I could just specify `enabled: false`, either in `dbt_project.yml` or in the `config` of the SQL statements for each individual model. But ideally there would be a DRY way of doing this somewhat closer to where these models are actually specified.

Answer (score 2):

One way of handle it will add `+enabled: false` in dbt_project.yml file for the folder you want to disable. That will disable all the models inside the folder. Something like this.

```
models:
  your_profile_name:
    experiments:
       experiment_4:
         +enabled: false
```

An extra yaml property file can be used to config individual models, in this case disable a model.

```
version: 2

models:
  - name: stg_f1_dataset__constructor_results
    config:
      enabled: false
      
  - name: stg_f1_dataset__constructor_standings
    config:
      enabled: false
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify this closer to where the `.sql` files that specify these models are located, and not in the central `dbt_project.yml` file? What would an appropriate `properties.yml` look like?

Comment: added an example for properties yaml file. For a whole folder, it is easier config in dbt_project.yml file

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own [YAML selector](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/yaml-selectors) for including or excluding models across your DBT project. You can even define several selectors for different use cases, I usually create my selectors.yml file in the root directory and define all of my selectors in there.

I haven't tested your setup but I believe you can do something similar to this:

```yml
selectors:
  - name: all_except_4
    description: Select all models except experiment_4 folder
    definition:
      union:
        - method: path
          value: models/experiments
        - exclude:
            - union:
              - method: path
                value: models/experients/experiment_4
```

You can check all the available methods [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/methods).

To use the selector just pass dbt the `--selector` flag with the selector_name you want to use:

```
dbt run --selector <selector_name>
```

I recommend you use `ls` command to test/debug while building your selector to list the models that dbt is selecting:

```
dbt ls --selector <selector_name>
```

Comment: How do I then use this to disable all models that match the selector?

Comment: You can use the `exclude` keyword in the yaml file to explicitly exclude models from the selector. The documentation isn't very clear on how to use it though... [Exclude selector](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/yaml-selectors#exclude)